# Regex for url without html tags

Tags: regex

I want to match url text without any html tags.

This is my regex:

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})
```

Problem is it also matches `https://XXXTEST.co.il</strong>`

I'd like to get regex to match only `https://XXXTest.co.il` out of `https://XXXTest.co.il</strong>`

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `[^___]` blocks, you're accidentally including < and >, which are not URL safe characters. If you change your regex to only allow URL safe characters (or explicitly exclude <) then it should fix it.

Comment: It is not my own regex buiilt from 0, So Im not that expert with this regex..
Could you point exactly where the block is

Comment: Anywhere you see square brackets with a caret just inside, like [^\s], that means match any character that is not inside that set. If you put < and > inside those square brackets as well, they will be excluded too. In the case of [^\s], that will look like [^\s<>]. It looks like that happens in 4 places in your pattern.